# Performance issue with HTTP request in Julia API

Tags: performance, http, julia

Exploring the [Oxygen package](https://github.com/OxygenFramework/Oxygen.jl) to build APIs I found this I haven't been able to solve

1. When I run this API (with a 150 ms sleep to simulate the time taken by a model):

```
using Oxygen

@get "/model" function()
    sleep(0.15)
    return json("ok")
end

serve(port = 8001)
```

**I reach about 560 RPS** (with concurrency = 100)

`ab -n1000 -c100 'http://localhost:8001/model'`

```
Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8001

Document Path:          /model
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.756 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      83000 bytes
HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
Requests per second:    569.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       175.556 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.756 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          46.17 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

When I build another Oxygen API consuming the previous one

```
using Oxygen
using HTTP

@get "/test" function()
    response = HTTP.get("http://localhost:8001/model") # sleep(0.15) - Just this line is different
    return json("ok")
end

serve(port = 8002)
```

**I reach only around 100 RPS** even using 4 threads with serveparallel. I would expect to see an RPS number closer to 560.

`ab -n1000 -c100 'http://localhost:8002/test'`

```
Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8002

Document Path:          /test
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   9.815 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      83000 bytes
HTML transferred:       4000 bytes
Requests per second:    101.89 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       981.455 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       9.815 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          8.26 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

I think the issue is in the HTTP.get request on the Julia API maybe there is a better way to do it or ways to speed it up. Any hint is welcome.

I tested it in:
Julia version: 1.9.4 and 1.10.1
Oxygen version: 1.4.9 and 1.5.0
HTTP version: 1.10.2

If I do the same with python using FastAPI and request

```
import requests
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test")
def test():
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:8001/model")
    return "ok"
```

**With just one worker** (uvicorn api_test_nested:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8003 --workers 1) **I get around 220 RPS** with 4 workers I almost reach the 450 RPS

`ab -n1000 -c100 'http://localhost:8003/test'`

```
Server Software:        uvicorn
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8003

Document Path:          /test
Document Length:        6 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.436 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      149000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6000 bytes
Requests per second:    225.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       443.618 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.436 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          32.80 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

**Progress:**

I changed the `/test` API to **use curl instead of HTTP.jl** and I got a huge improvement so I'm almost sure there is something strange with HTTP.jl

```
using Oxygen

@get "/test" function()
    response = run(`curl http://localhost:8001/model`) # instead of HTTP.request("GET", "http://localhost:8001/model")
    return json("ok")
end

serve(port = 8002)
```

**With this small change I go from 100 RPS to about 440 RPS**, much closer to 560 RPS I get from `/model` and twice the RPS from FastAPI with one worker.

Any suggestions?